# Ignore Iconv::IllegalSequence while using Ruby WWW::Mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I've encountered the Iconv::IllegalSequence error on some web pages when using mechanize lib. Is there a way to make mechanize just omit ill encoded characters and return the "cut" page? I'm aware of the [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586163/iconvillegalsequence-when-using-wwwmechanize), but I'd rather discard some characters on the page, then re-implement encoding guessing. TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to change line 40 in util.rb from

```
Iconv.iconv(code, "UTF-8", s).join("")
```

to

```
Iconv.iconv("#{code}//IGNORE", "UTF-8", s).join("")
```

or

```
Iconv.conv("#{code}//IGNORE", "UTF-8", s)
```

Comment: Also consider using `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` for mixed encoding.
check https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet/issues/17 and
http://ruby.11.x6.nabble.com/Reliable-character-encodings-conversion-td3332842.html

Answer (score 1):

Better solution is not changing source of util.rb, but adding in your own code something like that:

```
Mechanize::Util.send(:define_method, 'self.encode_to' ) { |*args|
  encoding = args[0]
  str = args[1]

  if NEW_RUBY_ENCODING
    str.encode(encoding)
  else
    Iconv.conv(encoding.to_s + '//IGNORE', "UTF-8", str)
  end

}
```