# How to set the mechanize page encoding?

Tags: ruby, encoding, mechanize

I'm trying to get a page with an ISO-8859-1 encoding clicking on a link, so the code is similar to this:

```
page_result = page.link_with( :text => 'link_text' ).click
```

So far I get the result with a wrong encoding, so I see characters like:

```
'T�tulo:' instead of 'Título:'
```

I've tried several approaches, including:

- Stating the encoding in the first request using the agent like:

  ```
  @page_search = @agent.get(
    :url => 'http://www.server.com',
    :headers => { 'Accept-Charset' => 'ISO-8859-1' } )
  ```
- Stating the encoding for the page itself

  ```
    page_result.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
  ```

But I must be doing something wrong: a simple puts always show the wrong characters.

Do you know how to state the encoding?

Thanks in advance,

Added: Executable example:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'

WWW::Mechanize::Util::CODE_DIC[:SJIS] = "ISO-8859-1"

@agent = WWW::Mechanize.new

@page = @agent.get(
  :url => 'http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloSimpleFilter.do?cache=init&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es',
  :headers => { 'Accept-Charset' => 'utf-8' } )

puts @page.body
```

Answer (score 10):

Hey you can just do a:

```
agent.page.encoding = 'utf-8'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It hard to use 'agent.page.encoding' in real code, but idea is correct and very helpful, thanks!

Comment: I spent many hours trying to fix this problem until I stumbled upon your answer -- thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is correct, but in my code it looks slightly different:

```
agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://example.com')

page.encoding = 'windows-1251'

page.search('p').each do |para|
  puts para.text
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This tip fixed a related issue regarding form encoding that was in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was my mistake: I come from a Java background and there strings are internally converted to utf-16. I forgot Ruby doesn't do it. Mechanize was recovering the page flawlessly, but I needed to convert the data via iconv.

**Mental note: Ruby stores the strings without converting its encoding.**

Comment: you might also wanna try ruby 1.9 if possible, they added a whole lot of [unicode stuff](http://blog.nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, Mechanize will try to detect the encoding itself (using the NKF core Ruby library) to guess the encoding) and sometimes fails.

Maybe this might help:
`WWW::Mechanize::Util::CODE_DIC[:SJIS] = "ISO-8859-1"`

I'm not too sure about the exact syntax, but I think the CODE_DICT Hash might be a good place to look :)
I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586163/iconvillegalsequence-when-using-wwwmechanize) a while back.